# how to specify different IP addresses for different users in Tsung

Tags: ip, automated-tests, tsung

is it possible to specify users IP addresses in Tsung?
Because in Apache logs, the users have the same IP address, the IP of the machine from which testing have been done. I want to specify somehow in Tsung, that it should generate new users with unique identifiers for being possible to distinguish them on Apache logs.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

vhost is only supported by jabber/XMPP plugin not by HTTP or others. Visit http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual.html#htoc58 to get more.

If you want to specify IP , maybe use more slave in your cluster ? But we can not specify IP per user .